# How to dynamically adjust width of nav-tabs so it fills up the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I have a nav tab that looks like this:

[image]

I am using ellipses however I don't like how my nav is scattered in second line. I don't want to use nav-justfied instead be able to squeeze my

so it fits in screen and user don't have to scroll horizontally.

like below

[image: Like this]

My code so far

```
.nav-tabs>li:not(.active)>a {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: 3px solid #9d9d9d;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.nav-tabs {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">

  <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
    {% block tab_buttons %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>

  <li role="presentation" class="{% if '/hosts' in request.path %}active {% endif %}inverse"><a href="{% url 'sc:events:hosts-list' event.id %}" role="tab">Hosts</a></li>
  {% for tab in event.benchmarks.all %}
  <li role="presentation" class="{% if 'summary' in request.path and tab == benchmark %}active {% endif %}inverse"><a href="{% url 'sc:events:benchmarks-summary' event.id tab.id %}" role="tab">{{ tab.name }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking but it sounds like you could benefit from using:

[display flex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp#flex-direction) on your nav.

If you're loading the content on the same page (like an admin panel), I'd highly recommend [Jquery Tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Display:inline-flex;` css property on tabs.